# How to tell the difference between a class with the legitimate size of 1 and an empty class?

Tags: c++

I have a template class, among the template variables is an optional typename for a meta data class in case the inheriting classes should need it. The point of this class is to manage IO which also includes meta data.

For performance reasons, the class doesn't perform meta IO if the meta type is empty.
To my surprise though, the size of an empty class (which the meta type defaults to) is not 0 but 1.

This doesn't pose a huge problem since its unlikely that any kind of meta type will have the size of 1 and I can just check if the size is > 1 but hypothetically, how could one tell the difference between an empty class and a class that is packed to contain 1 byte?

Comment: I suspect finding that out is implementation specific at best. The reason an empty class is padded to 1 byte is probably so that pointers to different instances point to a unique address. Otherwise an array of empty classes would have the same address for every array element and looping over it would most likely break.

Comment: @Praveen Not a duplicate.  That question asks why an empty class has size 1, this wants to know how to tell if a class is empty.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Empty Base Class Optimization? In particular, `struct Test : T { U u }` can have `sizeof(Test)==sizeof(U)`. This may also be a good method to store your meta type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::is_emty<T>::value` from the header `type_traits` to tell whether a type is totally empty.

Also, you can derive from the type (assuming that's possible) with a type that has a known size and check whether the parent class adds anything to the size of the derived class or not. This works because compilers are allowed (required to?) perform the "empty base optimization".

For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct KnownSize : T {uint64_t whatever;}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool IsEmpty () {return sizeof(KnownSize<T>) <= sizeof(uint64_t);}
```

(fair warning: haven't tried this code; probably won't work.)
Quite possibly, there are alignment issues (there always is!) and maybe others that might break this. But I think all of them can be overcome.